# Just rotate image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

what is my mistake?

I just want to rotate original image and save him to output folder.

```
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

for image in Path('/home/lol/Pictures').glob('**/*.png'):
    img = Image.open(image)
    img = img.rotate(180)
    img.save('/home/lol/Pictures/output/{}'.format(image.name))

    print('Done: {}'.format(image))
```

Console output:

```
Done: /home/lol/Pictures/image.png
Done: /home/lol/Pictures/output/image.png
```

And the picture in output is the same like original.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/) post could help you.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the script is successfully rotating `Pictures/image.png` and saving it in your `output` directory. But it doesn't stop there: `glob` iterates its way into the `output` folder, and rotates all of those pictures too. So your original `output/image.png` gets overwritten with a copy of `output/image.png`, except rotated 180 degrees. In other words, it's your original image, rotated 360 degrees - an identical copy.

You should make sure that `glob` doesn't iterate over the `output` directory. You could move `output` to somewhere other than `home/lol/Pictures`. Or perhaps you could manually skip over the output directory, with something like `if "/output/" in image: continue`.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, I get it.